# Proof that $P(x\ge 6)<1/10$

Tags: probability

X is a nonegative random variable.
Expectation $E(2^X)=5$.

Proof that $P(X\geqslant6)\lt\frac{1}{10}$ .

It looks like probability generating function
 $G(z)=E(z^X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_iz^{x_i}$ and $G(2)=5$.

But what to do with that?

Answer (score 5):

Are you familiar with Markov's inequality? The event $\{X\ge 6\}$ is the same as the event $\{2^X\ge 2^6\}$.